Why $〈a,tr(b)〉=〈res(a),b〉$ imply $res^*=tr$?
This question is about Tate's celebrated paper. http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1956-1958__4__265_0.pdf

In short, my question is, why $(12) :〈a,tr(b)〉_K=〈res(a),b〉_L$ in　p.268 of the paper implies
commutativeness of square diagram in p.273?

I will explain the question above. While all the gradients are related to the theory of elliptic curves and Galois cohomology,but it might simply be an elementary problem in pairing or group theory.
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve.
Let $〈,〉_K: H^1(G_K,E)\times H^0(G_K,E)\to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ be the local　Tate pairing.
Let $L/K$ be a quadratic extension.
It is known that $(12) : 〈a,tr(b)〉_K=〈res(a),b〉_L$ where $tr$ is $P\to P+\sigma *P$ where $\sigma *$ denotes usual action of $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ and $res : H^1(G_K,E)\to H^1(G_L,E)$ is restriction map(This is $(12)$ in p.268 of the linked paper.
My question is, Why $res^*=tr$ holds ? Here, $res^*$ denotes dual of restriction. Definition of the dual of $\phi : A \to B$ is $A^* \to B^*,\ f \mapsto f \circ \phi$.

I might be confused -- I would define the "dual" (or adjoint) of a morphism on a vector-space to be exactly this (the dual of $\phi$ is the unique $\psi$ with $<\phi v, w> = <v, \psi w>$ for all $v, w$).

@hunter Definition of the dual of $\phi : A \to B$ is $A^* \to B^*,\ f \mapsto f \circ \phi$. I have added this to the question.

See the answers there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177979/dual-of-the-linear-map

@Nolord, my question asks why my definition implies hunter's in this context. I might have overlooked something, but in your link, I cannot find any reason for this.

Don't know about this case but elsewhere the dual is often defined the way Hunter describer assuming that there is a suitable non-degenerate bilinear pairing. Of course, it would still be nice to see different descriptions of dual to co-operate to this extent. +1

Define $\psi_K: H^0(G_K,E) \rightarrow H^1(G_K,E)^{\ast}$ given by $y \mapsto \langle \cdot ,\, y \rangle_K$ (same for $L$).
Now, $res^{\ast} \circ \psi_L$ is by definition the map $z \in H^0(G_L,E) \mapsto \langle \cdot ,\, z \rangle \circ res \in H^1(G_K,E)^{\ast}$.
Now, if $z \in H^0(G_L,E)$,
$$res^{\ast}(\psi_L(z))=\langle\cdot,\, z\rangle_L \circ res = \langle res(\cdot),\, z\rangle_L=\langle \cdot,\, tr(z)\rangle_K=\psi_K(tr(z)).$$
This is what the sentence “$res^{\ast}=tr$” means.
